# FFT on WP7 shows two mirrors

Tags: c#, algorithm, windows-phone-7

Hello
I'm exploring the audio possibilities of the WP7 platform and the first stumble I've had is trying to implement a FFT using the Cooley-Tukey method. The result of that is that the spectrogram shows 4 identical images in this order: one normal, one reversed, one normal, one reversed.
The code was taken from another C# project (for desktop), the implementation and all variables seem in place with the algorithm.
So I can see two problems right away: reduced resolution and CPU wasted to generate four identical spectrograms.
Given a sample size of 1600 (could be 2048) I know have only 512 usable frequency information which leaves me with a 15Hz resolution for an 8kHz frequency span. Not bad, but not so good either.

Should I just give up on the code and use NAudio? I cannot seem to have an explanation why the spectrum is quadrupled, input data is ok, algorithm seems ok.

Comment: You want comments on an algorithm / implementation that we cannot see?

Comment: I thought it was standard. Anyway: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/FftGuitarTuner.aspx

Comment: Perhaps I did not explained the problem very well.Imagine that 2048samples of input get converted to 2048 bins of frequency amplitudes(in place).Now let's assume I have the common 50Hz peak showing up around the zero position.This is quite normal,but I also get the same peak around the 1024 position and 2048 position.I know that the FFT spectrum is centered around zero,but mine is also centered at half input size position and at full length position.This means that in those transformed 2048 samples I get 4 spectrums(2x'normal',2xmirrored). I cannot think of any logical reason why this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to NAudio and now the FFT works. However I might have found the cause (I probably won't try to test again): when I was constructing an array of double to feed into the FFT function, I did something like:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i+= sizeof(short))
            {
                samples[i] = ReadSample(buffer, i);
            }
```

For reference, 'samples' is the double[] input to fft, ReadSample is something that takes care of little/big endian. Can't remember right now how the code was, but it was skipping every odd sample.

My math knowledge has never been great but I'm thinking this induces some aliasing patterns which might in the end produce the effect I experienced.

Anyway, problem worked around, but thanks for your input and if you can still explain the phenomenon I am grateful.

Comment: I'm guessing it skipped every other sample because you're iterating through a `short` array and incrementing the index by `sizeof(short)` which is 2. Unless `buffer` is a `byte` array, in which case you're still skipping every other byte.

Comment: samples was a double[], the buffer was short[]. I was iterating correctly through buffer[], but was filling the samples[] every other index which left me with 'holes'.

Comment: It doesn't matter what type of array `buffer` is - you're skipping every other element because `sizeof(short)` = `2`. If your code appeared to work, it was probably because your original input was stereo, so you end up doing an FFT on only the left channel.

Comment: That's a great comment and a future gotcha, but in this case it didn't happen - WP7 input is 16Khz mono. I made a mistake in my comment, it should read like: buffer=byte[2048], samples=double[2048]. The problem was that since I read short from a byte[] I should have a half size samples[].

Answer (score 1):

This sounds correct. You have 2 mirrors, I can only assume that one is the Real part and the other is the Image part. This is standard FFT.

From the real and image you can compute the magnitude or amplitude of each harmonic which is more common or compute the angle or phase shift of each harmonic which is less common.

Gilad.

Comment: The algorithm did magnitude computation and the output was a double-mirrored (but otherwise correct) image.

Comment: Here's the part that converts the complex image into a spectrogram:
`            // calculate spectrogram
            double[] spectrogram = new double[length];
            for (int i = 0; i < spectrogram.Length; i++)
            {
                spectrogram[i] = data[i].AbsPower2();
            }
            return spectrogram;`
I have to learn how to edit a comment. Data[i] is an array of Complex; AbsPower2 as its name implies returns the sum of the squares of imaginary and real parts.